# Mule Custom Transport Connector

Tags: mule, connector

I am trying to create a custom transport by [Creating Transport](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Creating+Transports) and
I created the transport successfully. But the issue is with the protocol it uses. So if I have created a custom transport named as **customT**, then my custom transport will listen at  **customT://{hostname}/{port}/**. But I want to use http or any other standard protocol to use this custom transport. Basically I am trying to modify the functionality of one of the standard transport provided by Mule.

So can anybody please help me with that and tell me that whether it is possible to extend existing http(or any other) transport connector provided by Mule or any other way to override in my custom transport.

I found one way to doing this by changing the protocol name in the `NameSpaceHandler` class in my custom connector.

```
  registerStandardTransportEndpoints("http",  URIBuilder.PATH_ATTRIBUTES);
```

But issue with this is that after providing http here it is not going to my custom written code, rather then it is going to Mule provided connector code.

Does anybody have idea how should I change this behavior ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not extending the existing HTTP transport instead of creating a new one and try to namespace-force it into Mule?

Comment: how can I extend the existing HTTP transport because as far as I have read the documentation of Mule, for extending the existing transport I would require to run the command to create a transport from the existing tansport source code directory, so mule keeps the existing code as it is and adds new classes. And while creating the transport I provided "http" in the answer to this question "Which Mule transports do you want to include in this project?", but still I didn't see any difference in the created transport project.

Comment: You can extend existing classes and register them as service overrides. The question is: what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi David, I am trying to create a custom transport connector to work on standard protocol like tcp. The actual purpose of this customization is to create Customize the MLLP connector to work over SSL and to accept any other HL7 message rather then just expecting HL7 ACK message. Kindly share if you have any other approach to achieve this.

Comment: Not sure what's the MLLP connector?! If what you intend to do is to create a custom protocol over TCP/IP (even with SSL), Mule supports this OOTB.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, I suggest that you create a custom protocol for the TCP transport and activate SSL on it.